# JAWS reader reads a year different depending on how you navigate to it

Tags: navigation, numbers, digits, jaws-screen-reader

I have a h3 element with a year in my HTML.

< h3>2022< /h3>
(but without the spaces)

I am using the JAWS reader to read the page.
If I use the arrow keys to navigate through the page JAWS will read the 2022 as separate digits 2 0 2 2.
If I use the H key to navigate through the headers on the page JAWS will read the 2022 as one number.

Is this a quirk of JAWS or is there something I can do to prevent this?
Maybe a setting in JAWS?
I would like the year to be read as one number.

Thanks,
Nell

Answer (score 0):

What browser and what version of JAWS?  It's working fine for me in JAWS 2020 (I don't have a license for the most recent version) and Chrome 100.

Pressing the H key, I hear *"2022, heading level 3"*.

Using the down arrow key, I hear *"heading level 3, 2022"*.

I did a simple test case with:

```html
<h3>2022</h3>
```

Comment: I just remembered something that the tester of our client mentioned. She has access to (I think) the Accessibility Object Model (AOM) which JAWS uses to read the text. The tester mentioned that she saw 2 spaces behind the 2022. If JAWS counts those 2 spaces as part of the number this could be the cause of the issue, since there is a setting in JAWS that specifies that 'more than 5 numbers' are read as separate digits. So I will have to now go in search of why those 2 spaces are generated. In the meantime I've changed the setting to 'more than 6 numbers' and it's read as a whole number now.

Comment: And to answer your actual question: I'm using Jaws 2022 and Chrome 101.

Comment: Yeah, I see that setting in the JAWS Setting Center but when I modified my example to have spaces before and/or after the "2022", I still couldn't hear them read as individual digits.  I tried regular spaces (0x20) as well as `&nbsp;`.  And I used the 'H' shortcut key and the downarrow key.

Comment: The AOM is available to everyone.  All browsers create an accessibility tree and surface that to the OS's API.  It's what the screen reader interacts with.  Anytime you change things in the DOM, the AOM is also updated.